# Trying to pull list via Onelogin API

Tags: api, get, onelogin

I'm attempting to pull a full list of users that have a specific app or Role on their onelogin account.

I've looked under both Roles and Users within the API but it doesn't appear it's possible to simply give the API a role name/ID and get all user's that are apart of it.

Is there an easy way to do this? It's to help automate auditing of auto-provisioned applications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described at the [API documentation, at the User section](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/get-users).
you can use "query parameters" in order to filter users.

In your case you want to filter by role_id.

Imagine you want all the users with the role_id = 1:

```
curl 'https://api.<us_or_eu>>.onelogin.com/api/1/users?role_id=1' \
     -X GET \
     -H "Authorization: bearer:<access_token>"
```

In order to get the list of available roles you can execute:

```
curl 'https://api.<us_or_eu>.onelogin.com/api/1/roles' \
-X GET \
-H "Authorization: bearer:<access_token>"
```

Comment: Thank you for this smartin! This worked **perfectly** :)